# what is the best way to write a file with data using Android Storage Access Framework?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, storage, storage-access-framework

I want to write a file with data using Android Storage Access Framework but I am facing some problems. in this below code I can create a file but the file is blank.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
                       intent.setType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,DATABASE_NAME+"_"+AppUtils.getCurrentDate()+".xls");
                       startActivityForResult(intent,CREATE_FILE);
```

if I use this below code then I can get writing access to throw the `Uri` from `onActivityResult`

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        intent.setType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                        startActivityForResult(intent,WRITE_FILE);
```

it makes my app-less user-friendly because the users will have to create a file first then they have to select it again for writing data on it. I am expecting something directly to create and write the file into the Android Storage Access Framework. is there any good way to do that. please help.

Comment: Why aren't you using the Uri returned by `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` in `onActivityResult`?

Comment: I tried it but it's not work. the result is a blank file which size is 0B

Comment: Well yeah, you need to write content into that Uri. What did you think you needed to do with that Uri?

Comment: is there any way to do that directly?